# Replacing 2 new lines and tab with string using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, tabs, newline

This seems really simple, but I have a string that I want to replace a string with a tab and 2 new lines and it isn't working.

```
string newString = "\tMyVariable : Bool\n\t\nEND_VAR";
string pattern = "\n\t\nEND_VAR";
string original = "VAR_GLOBAL\n\t\nEND_VAR\n";
string updatedString = Regex.Replace(original,pattern,newString);
```

updatedString never gets updated, it remains at "VAR_GLOBAL\n\t\nEND_VAR\n", where it should be "VAR_GLOBAL\tMyVariable : Bool\n\t\nEND_VAR\n". I'm not sure why it won't change.

Comment: In the pattern you need to also escape the backslash in order to the regex engine knows what you want to replace, that is, `string pattern = "\\n\\t\\nEND_VAR";`

Comment: Why not just use `string.Replace` since your regular expression is just plain text?

Comment: I started with string.Replace for simplicity and since it wasn't working, I moved onto RegEx.Replace since there was more examples of it.  @dcg answer worked great!

Comment: Not my answer but thanks anyway. Just give you some thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Regex might not be the best suited for such scenario, please find below a sample code which will suit your needs ([Regex test](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%5Cn%5C%5Ct%5C%5CnEND_VAR&i=VAR_GLOBAL%5Cn%5Ct%5CnEND_VAR%5Cn&r=%5CtMyVariable%20%3A%20Bool%5Cn%5Ct%5CnEND_VAR)).

```
string newString = "\tMyVariable : Bool\n\t\nEND_VAR";
string pattern = "\\n\\t\\nEND_VAR";
string original = "VAR_GLOBAL\n\t\nEND_VAR\n";
string updatedString = Regex.Replace(original,pattern,newString);
```

The other (maybe simplier) option would be to do a straight replace like in:

```
string newString = "\tMyVariable : Bool\n\t\nEND_VAR";
string updatedString = newString.Replace("\n\t\n", "\t");
```

Comment: I need to be able to replace the end of the string multiple times with variables, so I'll use the former example.  Thanks!